# Count how many is_shared=1 per item_id (mysql, magento)

Tags: mysql, magento2

I would like to count how many items with same 'item_id' have value of 'is_shared' = 1.

**Example 1.** for item_id=8517 the value of shared_count should be 0, because there were 0 items with item_id=8517 that have value of is_shared=1

**Example 2.** for item_id=8519 the value of shared_count should be 1, because there is one item with item_id=8519 and value of is_shared set to 1

[image: Database table]

Mysql Query:

```
                'MIN(`main_table`.`id`) AS id',
                'main_table.item_id',
                'main_table.course_id',
                'main_table.code',
                'main_table.student_id',
                'main_table.product_data',
                'main_table.is_shared',
                'main_table.recipient_email',
                'MAX(`main_table`.`is_shareable`) AS is_shareable',
                'MAX(`main_table`.`grace_period_end`) AS grace_period_end',
                'MAX(`main_table`.`expired_at`) AS expired_at',
                'COUNT(`main_table`.`student_id`) AS student_count',
                '(select count(`main_table2`.`student_id`) from iways_enrollment_item as main_table2 where `main_table2`.`item_id`=`main_table`.`item_id` and `main_table2`.type_id=\'bundle\') as student_count_bundle',
                'MAX(`sales_order_item`.`qty_invoiced` - `sales_order_item`.`qty_canceled`) as qty_paid',
                '(SELECT IF(COUNT(`iei`.`student_id`), 1, 0) ' .
                'FROM `iways_enrollment_item` `iei` WHERE `iei`.`student_id` = ' . $this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId() . ' AND `iei`.`course_id` = `main_table`.`course_id` ' .
                'AND (`iei`.`expired_at` >= CURDATE() OR `iei`.`expired_at` IS NULL)) AS current_user_enrolled',
                '(SELECT IF(COUNT(`soi`.`parent_item_id`), 1, 0) FROM `sales_order_item` `soi` WHERE `soi`.`parent_item_id` = `sales_order_item`.`item_id`) AS is_parent',
```

Comment: please share your data as text rather than image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try summing the boolena resul for is_shared=1

```
select  item_id, sum(is_shared=1)
from my_table  
group by  item_id
```

or count  for filtered result

```
select  item_id, count(*)
from my_table  
where is_shared = 1
group by  item_id
```